# How to decode an invalid json string in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I wonder if there is a way to decode a JSON-like string.

I got string:

```
'{ hotel: { id: "123", name: "hotel_name"} }'
```

It's not a valid JSON string, so I can't decode it directly with the python API.
Python will only accept a stringified JSON string like:

```
 '{ "hotel": { "id": "123", "name": "hotel_name"} }'
```

where properties are quoted to be a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [demjson](http://deron.meranda.us/python/demjson/) module, which has ability to decode in non-strict mode.

```
In [1]: import demjson
In [2]: demjson.decode('{ hotel: { id: "123", name: "hotel_name"} }')
Out[2]: {u'hotel': {u'id': u'123', u'name': u'hotel_name'}}
```

Comment: Didn't know about that module - will have to check that out + 1

Comment: Neat, will use this module! +1.

Answer (score 4):

[@vartec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511364/857390) has already pointed out `demjson`, which works well for slightly invalid JSON. For data that's even less JSON compliant I've written [`barely_json`](https://github.com/torfsen/barely_json):

```
from barely_json import parse
print(parse('[no, , {complete: yes, where is my value?}]'))
```

prints

```
[False, '', {'complete': True, 'where is my value?': ''}]
```

Comment: It is more robust than demjson.

Answer (score 3):

You could try and use a wrapper for a JavaScript engine, [like **pyv8**.](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/)

```
import PyV8
ctx = PyV8.JSContext()
ctx.enter()
# Note that we need to insert an assignment here ('a ='), or syntax error.
js = 'a = ' + '{ hotel: { id: "123", name: "hotel_name"} }'
a = ctx.eval(js)
a.hotel.id
>> '123' # Prints
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant and not robust (and easy to break), but it may be possible to kludge it with something like:

```
kludged = re.sub('(?i)([a-z_].*?):', r'"\1":', string)
# { "hotel": { "id": "123", "name": "hotel_name"} }
```

You may find that using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples) and the `parsePythonValue.py` example could do what you want as well... (or modified fairly easily to do so) or the `jsonParser.py` could be modified to not require quoted key values.