# How can I load a string that looks like json?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a [url](http://webresource.c-ctrip.com/code/cquery/resource/address/flight/flight_new_poi_gb2312.js), it defines every city's name and code in china.

I can use regular expression get the target string that looks like this:

```
{'Hot':[{display: "Beijing", data: "Beijing|Beijing(BJS)|1|BJS"}, 
{display: "Shanghai", data: "Shanghai|Shanghai(SHA)|2|SHA"}...]}
```

I want to use `json.loads(str)` to convert the string to a json object,but it will throw an exception, I guess because the string isn't a standard json string.

So I want to parse the string,mapping every city'name and code like:

```
Beijing - BJS
Shanghai - SHA
```

How can I do that?

------------------2016-07-06------------------

Here is my code.

```
def parse_city_code():
    url = 'http://webresource.c-ctrip.com/code/cquery/resource/address/flight/flight_new_poi_gb2312.js'
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

    data_str = response.read().decode('GBK')

    search = re.search('cQuery.jsonpResponse.suggestion=(\{.+\})',data_str)
    if(search):
        data_str = '"'+search.group(1)+'"'
    else:
        data_str = ''

    json.loads(data_str)
```

It will throw a exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/twlsoft/PycharmProjects/ctrip-flight-ticket/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    parse_city_code()
  File "C:/Users/twlsoft/PycharmProjects/ctrip-flight-ticket/main.py", line 19, in parse_city_code
    json.loads(data_str)
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 19 (char 18)
```

Because the data is not a valid json data?

------------------2016-07-06------------------

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38206990/how-can-i-load-a-string-that-looks-like-json?noredirect=1#comment63838198_38206990).

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: the json data packet is prepended by this string `cQuery.jsonpResponse={};cQuery.jsonpResponse.suggestion=`, read the string skipping these initial characters, and you'll be on your way.

Comment: Tried [`demjson`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12511364/771848) on your sample string - worked.

Comment: My notebook is in my office,now is 23:19PM here,tomorrow morning I will show you what I have tried first time,thank you.@Robᵩ

Comment: @HaleemurAli I already skip these characters.I just using the data like ```{'Hot':[{display: "Beijing", data: "Beijing|Beijing(BJS)|1|BJS"}, 
{display: "Shanghai", data: "Shanghai|Shanghai(SHA)|2|SHA"}...]}```,But it is not work

Comment: @alecxe Thanks~I will try it~ :P