# decode json in json with python

Tags: python, json

When I try to load following json in python:

```
"foo": {
            "foo_id": "1",
            "foo_name": "i",
            "foo_client_id": "2",
            "foo_client": "b",
        }
```

I got following error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

How do I parse this as a legal json?

Comment: 1) Wrap `foo` in another object (`{}`). 2) Remove trailing comma after `b`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decode an invalid json string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511159/how-to-decode-an-invalid-json-string-in-python)

Comment: What you have is not in valid JSON format — which doesn't allow that comma at the end of the last item (unlike Python).

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid JSON due to the missing enclosing brackets and the trailing comma. However, it's valid [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML):

```
import yaml

data = '''
"foo": {
        "foo_id": "1",
        "foo_name": "i",
        "foo_client_id": "2",
        "foo_client": "b",
    }
'''
yaml.safe_load(data)  # returns a dict
```